# How long should a 10mb .svg import file take to load in Blender?

Tags: mesh, import

I am trying to load a 9.6Mb .svg file into blender and it is still working on it after 45 min.

Hardware is a duel Xeon 32 core workstation, Titan X video, 128Gb Ram, 1Tb SSD

Comment: Best report this to the bug tracker. Likely there is some redundant calculations going on.

Comment: I did some tests with different files, and it all comes down to how many objects blender has to create. One 11mb file imported in about 15sec. While another 5mb svg took about 7mins. Congratulations on being so patient. From that we all learned that large files really will import.

Answer (score 3):

It just finished after 90 min, it is a very complex file so I should have been more patient.

I also notice that although Blender will use most of my cores for other tasks, when doing this import it only used 1 core, any way to change this setting?

Comment: I think the file is too large for Blender it has 4.8 million verts, every task is very slow.

Comment: There is no option to enable more than one thread for this. Using multiple cpu's requires programming to specifically handle the task that way, time consuming tasks like rendering and simulations will get that effort, importing a file would not be expected to benefit so will only use one core.